# Modeling for Graph DBs

Tags: database, graph, model

Coming from as SQL/NoSQL background I am finding it quite challenging to model (efficiently that is) the simplest of exercises on a Graph DB.

While different technologies have limitations and best practices, I am uncertain whether the mindset that I am using while creating the models is the correct one, hence, I am in the need of guidance, advice and/or resources to help me get closer to the right practices.

---

The initial exercise I have tried is representing a file share entire directory (subfolders and files) in a graph DB. For instance some of the attributes and queries I would like to include are;

- The hierarchical structure of the folders
- The aggregate size at the current node
- Being able to search based on who created a file/folder
- Being able to search on file types

This brings me to the following questions

1. When/Which attributes should be used for edges. Only those on which I intend to search? Only relationships?
2. Should I wish to extend my graph capabilities, for instance, search on files bigger than X? How does one try to maximize the future capabilities/flexibility of the model so that such changes do not cause massive impacts.

---

Currently I am exploring InfiniteGraph and TitanDB.

Answer (score 0):

1) The only attribute I can think of to describe an edge in a folder hierarchy is whether it is a contains or contained-by relationship.

(You don't even need that if you decide to consider all your edges one or the other.  In your case, it looks like you'll almost always be interrogating descendants to search and to return aggregate size).

This is a lot simpler than a network, or a hierarchy where the edges may be of different types.  Think an organization chart that tracks not only who manages whom, but who supports whom, mentors whom, harasses whom, whatever.

2) I'm not familiar with the two databases you mentioned, but Neo4J allows indexes on node properties, so adding an index on file_size should not have much impact.  It's also "schema-less," so that you can add attributes on the fly and various nodes may contain different attributes.